# Отправка формы в iframe скриптом

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!
У меня в iframe есть форма, её нужно отправить по определённому события в родительском окне. Как это сделать? прошу примеры js или js+jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот примерно как можно привязать к элементу во фрейме обработчик своего события.

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body').bind('callmod',function(){

                    alert('Yahoooo!!!!');

                });
```

Comment: Интересный вариант. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
function changechild(){
    var x = document.getElementById('fr');
    var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);
    y = y.document || y;
    y.body.innerHTML = "__works!__";
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="changechild()" value="change" id="bt">
<iframe src="test.html" id="fr"></iframe>
test.html находится на том же домене
```

Второй вариант: слушать из фрейма события из родительского документа. Код написать?

**Дописано**

test.html:

```
<script>
var flag = 0;
function doAction(){
    flag = 1;
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="doAction()" value="change" id="bt">
<iframe src="test2.html"></iframe>
test2.html находится на том же домене
```

test2.html:

```
<script>
var flag = 0;
function checkAction(){
    if(window.parent.flag && !flag){
        flag = 1;
        document.getElementById('bt').value = '__works!__';
    }
    setTimeout(checkAction, 50);
}
checkAction();
</script>

<input type="button" value="change" id="bt">
```

Comment: Да давай! знания лишними не бывают!